# Существует ли такой селектор?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Я хочу выбрать все input на разных уровнях вложенности в div с id = "dv1". Как это можно быстрее всего сделать с помощью jquery?

```
<div id="dv1">
    <input>
    <div>
        <input>
        <div>
            <input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.....

```
let inputs = $('#dv1 input');
```

Comment: Никогда и не догадывался, что такие селекторы работают на всех уровнях вложенности 0_0 спасибо вам.

Comment: Это обычные селекторы css. Всё что нужно - знать как они работают.